# Calling multiple commands via system() under windows doesn't work

Tags: c++, windows, shell, command, system

So basiclly im trying to use this:

```
int main()
    {
    
    system("adb kill-server \n"
                   "adb devices \n"
                   "adb start-server & \n"
                   "var=$(adb shell \"pidof com.rok\")\n"
                   "AFTER=`echo $var | sed 's/\\r//g'`\n"
                   "echo \"$AFTER\"\n"
                   "adb shell \"kill -STOP $AFTER\"\n"
                   "adb shell sleep 2\n"
                   "adb shell \"kill -CONT $AFTER\"");
                   
        return 0;
}
```

thing is this works in Clion without any error, but i must do this in visual studio and in visual studio i cannot do it like that i have to do every system command alone like:

```
        system("adb kill-server");
        system("adb devices");
        system("adb start-server");
        system("var=$(adb shell \"pidof com.rok\")");
        system("AFTER=`echo $var | sed 's/\\r//g'`");
        system("adb shell \"kill -STOP $AFTER\"");
```

so now the thing is when i run it like this everything works except this two lines:

```
        system("var=$(adb shell \"pidof com.rok\")");
        system("AFTER=`echo $var | sed 's/\\r//g'`");
```

even though they perfectly works on clion they dont in visual studio, i cannot find a way to solve this problem, this is the error:

```
'var' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
```

operable program or batch file.

```
'AFTER' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
```

operable program or batch file.

can anyone explain why this happens? and how can i solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each call of `system()` creates it's own shell as a subprocess, that's why multiple subsequent `system()` calls don't work if you e.g. try to set shell variables or do a `cd` command (expecting subsequent commands running in a specific directory).

The easiest way to do it, is to create a little temporary script file containing all the commands and execute this one with a single `system()` call:

```
// A raw string literal to make escaping easier 
// (see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal)
std::string cmds = R"xxx(
adb kill-server
adb devices
adb start-server & 
var=$(adb shell "pidof com.rok")
AFTER=`echo $var | sed 's/\r//g'`
echo "$AFTER"
adb shell "kill -STOP $AFTER"
adb shell sleep 2
adb shell "kill -CONT $AFTER"
)xxx";

std::ofstream cmdFile("tempCmdFile.cmd");

cmdFile << cmds;
cmdFile.close();

system("tempCmdFile.cmd");
```

You probably should tidy up the `tempCmdFile.cmd` up afterwards (i.e. remove it). But I hope you grasp what the code above does.

Also I am not so sure that

```
AFTER=`echo $var | sed 's/\r//g'`
```

will work in a windows shell, as you expect it to do. You probably need a different solution for that, or a *nix like shell to run it (e.g. MinGw provides one).

Comment: This actually worked too bad didn't look eariler, thanks.

Comment: @J.Steve Np. Glad to help.